# Can we get full count of results from a query that is extended by PagerDefault

Tags: 7, theming, paging

I have a query that is extended by `PagerDefault`.  I need to get the total count of results to show something like: "There are a total of 100 results, now showing 21-40".  I can't figure out where to get that number without building a separate query to run that doesn't use `PagerDefault`.

First place I looked was `theme_pager()`, which I'm already overriding in template.php.  The total result count is not passed there, only the current page (as `$variables['element']`).

I see that within `includes/pager.inc` in `pager_default_initialize()` only the current page number is sent to `theme_pager`, although the total items are passed to that function. (So close!)

Then I thought I could clone the query, but the query must be extended prior to adding conditions, so that wouldn't work.  I'll note that this isn't ideal either, because ideally, I would be able to get this total count without two db hits (as it would hit it for the count every time a user navigates the pagination).

So, does anyone know the best way to get the total count?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the existing pager class I don't think you can get that data without running the count query again. The total count is queried directly and saved to a local var before being passed off to `pager_default_initialize()`...it's not saved anywhere.

One option would be to extend the default class and use that for your pager queries. This is un-tested but I think it'll do the trick

```
class MyPager extends PagerDefault {

  /**
   * Overrides PagerDefault::execute().
   */
  public function execute() {
    // Add convenience tag to mark that this is an extended query. We have to
    // do this in the constructor to ensure that it is set before preExecute()
    // gets called.
    if (!$this->preExecute($this)) {
      return NULL;
    }

    // A NULL limit is the "kill switch" for pager queries.
    if (empty($this->limit)) {
      return;
    }
    $this->ensureElement();

    // Get the total items from our new statically cached function.
    $total_items = $this->getTotalItemCount();

    $current_page = pager_default_initialize($total_items, $this->limit, $this->element);
    $this->range($current_page * $this->limit, $this->limit);

    // Now that we've added our pager-based range instructions, run the query normally.
    return $this->query->execute();
  }

  /**
   * Cache the results of PagerDefault::getCountQuery().
   */
  public function getTotalItemCount() {
    static $total_items = NULL;

    if ($total_items === NULL) {
      $total_items = $this->getCountQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
    }

    return $total_items;
  }

}
```

You could then construct a query like the following

```
$query = db_select('table', 't')
  ->fields('t')
  ->condition('foo', 'bar')
  ->extend('MyPager');

$current_items = $query->execute();
$total_items = $query->getTotalItemCount();
```

There might be an easier way, but I just can't see it.

Comment: No, I think this is the easiest, and best, way.  Especially when I was considering duplicating the query without `extend()`, which I was very much against.  It requires an extra db hit, but you've mitigated that as much as possible by using `static`.  I can't edit the post because there isn't enough changes to be made, but `return $this->query->execute()` is missing the ending semi-colon.  Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked :) I added the semi-colon in, thanks

Answer (score 2):

After executing a query extending PagerDefault, you can at any time after that (even between different functions) call a global that stored the total product count.

```
// $results = $paged_query->execute();
// OR
// $results = some_function_that_executes_a_paged_query();
global $pager_total_items;
$count = $pager_total_items[0];
```

This works in Drupal 7 as far as I know, and I have had to use it before when having searches or paginated displays that needed a total count as well. I believe this avoids us having to use a whole second separate query.

This is the most "formal documentation" I could find on it from Drupal. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/pager_total_items/7.x
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!globals.api.php/global/pager_total_items/8.2.x

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total count of a query that is extended with PagerDefault with

```
  $num_rows = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```

This query fetches all nodes with pager and counts the total nodes

```
function _test() {
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
          ->extend('PagerDefault');
  $query->addField('n', 'nid');
  $num_rows = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
  $results = $query->execute();
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    drupal_set_message($result->nid); // print each row
    // do fancier stuff here
  }
  drupal_set_message($num_rows); // print total rows
  return 'test';
}
```

Comment: This solution works only on the first page of the listing.